# How to clip rendering to a given box

Tags: c++, opengl

How to clip rendering to a given box/rectangle in OpenGL?

E.g. instead of rendering it unclipped/cropped like this

[image: unclipped]

I want to make it clipped like this

[image: clipped]

Comment: Your entire question needs to be present within the text posted to stack overflow.   Content solely in links is not allowed.

Comment: You aren't allowed to add pictures to the question until you have 10 reputation points.  That is why they have the edit button.

Comment: You can post links, but you need to describe your question in the question.

Comment: @xaxxon: To properly describe a *graphics programming* question in prose one must know the proper terminology. But if OP already knew the proper terminology Google would have probably already helped him in the first place. When it comes to graphics questions an image or sketch is often the best was to phrase it (that's also why I think that graphics programming related questions, i.e. with the proper tags should not have a rep-threshold for inserting images).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using a combination of appropriately setting the viewport (`glViewport`), the scissor box (`glScissor`) and enable scissor testing (`glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST)`).

Comment: You shouldn't encourage bad questions.

Comment: @xaxxon: it's not a bad question, just needed a little bit of adjustment. C'mon, tho OP is a new user and you may still be able to educate rather than punishing him.

Comment: "punish" means not answering a question until it's been fixed per a comment left long ago?  The point is that the answer is supposed to help other people in the future as well as the original person.

Comment: @xaxxon: It's a perfectly legitimate question and I perfectly understood what OP wanted just from what was written there. You're expeting a newbie to ask a question with jargon and proper terminology, but if a newbie already knew the jargon and proper terminology the question would not arise in the first place. The difference between a good teacher and a bad one is, that good teachers are able to infer and the meaning of a question and see what the asker wanted without the asker knowing how to properly phrase it. Just because you didn't understand the question, that doesn mean others don't.

Comment: @xaxxon: Oh and BTW, there is no such thing like a "bad question". There might be question that are easier to answer than others, or where providing the proper information will get things answered much faster. But if you don't know what you have to look for / ask for, then the best way to get anywhere is to ask (maybe in unclear terms) and let knowledgeable people inquire further information, so that eventually you get to the subject matter. Also it's the only way to detect AB problems and direct misguided people to a better approach.

Comment: @datenwolf a bad question is one that is potentially insufficient to help others with the same question in the future.